# Should I wait to file 2023 if I am amended 2020

Tags: united-states, irs, refund, amended-tax-return

Last summer, the IRS sent me a notice saying that I didn’t file part of my W-2s in the year 2020 and that I owe an amount of $2900.

I am currently on a payment plan department while I get the amendment done. My question is should I wait and file my current year 2023 taxes until after the amendment is done.

Answer (score 2):

If there are any carry-forwards created by the amendment that you expect to affect the 2023 return, then you'd need to also amend the 2021 and 2022 returns first and wait with the 2023 until its done. Otherwise, there's no relationship between the two years and no dependencies between the returns, so you can file the 2023 return regardless of the amendment. Since you're on a payment plan the IRS should not withhold your 2023 refund to pay the 2020 obligations.